# Forcing figures to be displayed at top if page even if textheight is set to a custom value

Tags: floats, two-column

I'm creating a two column document and I noticed that two figures are sometimes displayed one below the other even if the adjacent column does not have any figures displayed. On debugging a bit, I found that this happens when textheight is assigned a custom value. Unfortunately, I can't unset that since that's a requirement on the document layout. Is there anyway I can work around this issue?

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Style stuff that is required for document start
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in} % Causes figures be placed in same column
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.50in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.0in}
% Style stuff that is required for document end

\begin{document}

\date{}

\title{\Large \bf Fancy title}

\author{
  {\rm Author}\\
   author@university.edu\\
   University
}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[t]
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tex}
  % https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/TeX_logo.svg/640px-TeX_logo.svg.png
  \captionof{figure}{\TeX}
  \label{fig:tex}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{latex}
  % https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/LaTeX_logo.svg/640px-LaTeX_logo.svg.png
  \captionof{figure}{\LaTeX}
  \label{fig:latex}
\end{figure}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not really related to changing textheight, figures are assigned to the left hand column if they meet the constraints specified, this is done before the second column text is set.

Comment: you could `\setcounter{topnumber}{1}` then at most one top float is allowed in a column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for insight into how figures are placed in two column format! I understand that the change(here increase) in textheight is partially the reason because it results more space is available in a column for placing the figures. Anyhow, setting topnumber fixes the issue and I ended up learning more about how floats are placed. Thanks a lot for the tip! Could you add an answer to the question? I could accept the answer if you do so.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You should add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per David's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307030/forcing-figures-to-be-displayed-at-top-if-page-even-if-textheight-is-set-to-a-cu#comment744975_307030).

## MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Style stuff that is required for document start
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in} % Causes figures be placed in same column
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.50in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.0in}
\setcounter{topnumber}{1} % To allow at most one top float in a column. 
% Style stuff that is required for document end

\begin{document}

\date{}

\title{\Large \bf Fancy title}

\author{
  {\rm Author}\\
   author@university.edu\\
   University
}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[t]
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{tex}
  % https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/TeX_logo.svg/640px-TeX_logo.svg.png
  \captionof{figure}{\TeX}
  \label{fig:tex}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \center
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{latex}
  % https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/LaTeX_logo.svg/640px-LaTeX_logo.svg.png
  \captionof{figure}{\LaTeX}
  \label{fig:latex}
\end{figure}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

## Before

[image: before]

## After

[image]